# How do I RemoveHandler (for global events) in a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

(using vb.net)

Hi,

In a class, I have a public shared event.

In my form, I have a usercontrol which I "AddHandler" to the shared event. But to avoid memory leaks (since the shared event never gets disposed as long as the application runs) how can I tell my usercontrol to RemoveHandler?

I tried to use the "Disposed" event, but it doesn't always seams like the usercontrol is disposed right away. I want to RemoveHandler as soon as the parent form closes.

What is best practice?

Comment: In c# `MyEvent -= MyEvent_Handler;`.

Answer (score 0):

EventHandlerList might be what you need - I use it to remove Click events from Buttons when some of my other controls have updated

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.removehandler.aspx